# converting LOGINV from Excel to C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm extracting a model from excel to a C# dll for computers without office.  One of the models calls the function [LOGINV](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Loginv-Function.html), which I can't find in the .NET framework (without using excel interop at least).  I found the [Open Office](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_LOGINV_function) description page, and a [java source entry](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/poi/poi/3.0-alpha3/poi-3.0-alpha3-sources.jar!/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/formula/functions/Loginv.java?format=ok), but no actual source entries that I can see.  Does anyone know where I could find the source for this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Octave (open source Matlab engine) contains a function called logninv, and the source is available online [here](http://octave3.0.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1:3.0.5-6ubuntu2/logninv_8m-source.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find Microsoft-provided source for the actual function that Excel runs. However, it shouldn't be too hard to take something like [An algorithm for computing the inverse normal cumulative distribution function](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/index.html) and adapt it to your needs. See also [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/680338-normsinv-function) which spells it out.

(Note that the first linked page computes what the documentation you linked to for `LOGINV` calls `NORMSINV`)

Comment: thanks for the links, I actually needed Normsinv also.  It did give me the idea about where to search for equivalent source.